# New Schwinn 700c (bike in a box) assembly

Tags: lubricant, bike-setup, new-bicycle-assembly

[image: i've inserted handles not connected[2]
[image: overview]

I just got my bike delivered and having more difficulty than I thought putting it together.

After buying proper tools it should be okay. Aside from set up tips, does the suggestion about like lubrication for set up a must?

I cannot find any.

Comment: If you don't do things like grease your pedals or seatpost, you might end up with them being seized in place and not be able to remove them. Otherwise, a lot of new bikes come in a way that you only need a hex key set to put them together (and maybe a small crescent wrench for putting on the pedals).

Comment: Okay. So just like grease the pedals and seatpost upon entry to the frame? Can I use like grease from computers or cars or something special needed?

Comment: There should be no need to grease bearings on a new bike.  A drop of lube on each pedal where it threads into the crank is sometimes helpful, though.  A touch of lube on the seatpost can also be helpful, but one must use special stuff if the post or frame is carbon.  Otherwise, auto grease or motor oil is fine.

Comment: Automotive (e.g. bearing) grease is fine. So is white lithium grease from the hardware store. It would help if you put pictures of how assembled your bike is.

Comment: Okay I'll do that one second.

Comment: I'm still new so it won't let me do a lot but I posted the image in the original question. it came out of the box pretty set up. I have to attach the handlebars, pedals, and front wheel plus a few minor things.

Comment: @Zoogy.Bear - Did you put the stem (thing the handlebars are attached to that goes into the frame) into the frame?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments grease the pedals and seat post to prevent them from seizing.  Quill stem you might grease.

The bearings should come lubricated.

Pretty much any grease (except computer).  Bicycle grease is more for bearings but you could use it. If you are going to buy some just get general purpose grease.

Tip pedals are right and left.

Comment: Yeah, definitely observe that the pedals have an "L" and an "R" stamped on them somewhere, probably on the end of the threaded shaft.  Make sure the "L" pedal goes into the left side and the "R" pedal into the right side.  And observe that the "L" pedal will be threaded "backwards".

Comment: When threading in the pedals, DON'T FORCE THEM.  If the threads do not easily fit, stop and check what you're doing.  Only the last turn or two should be difficult.  (Though definitely use a wrench to do the final tightening, and get them quite tight.)